# Quartz.net server encounters two jobs with same name?

Tags: xml, quartz.net-2.0

What happens when the Quartz.net server (running as a Windows service) encounters two jobs with identical names and groups? For example:

```
    <job>
        <name>SampleJob</name>
        <group>DEFAULT</group>
        <job-class>com.xyz.SampleJob</job-class>
        <job-data-map>
            <entry>
                <key>Param1</key>
                <value>HOT</value>
            </entry>
        </job-data-map>
    </job>
    <job>
        <name>SampleJob</name>
        <group>DEFAULT</group>
        <job-class>com.xyz.SampleJob</job-class>
        <job-data-map>
            <entry>
                <key>Param2</key>
                <value>COLD</value>
            </entry>
        </job-data-map>
    </job>
```

Does the server overwrite the first one? or throw an error?

Answer (score 0):

In hindsight this was a silly question..

I ran the code on the server and the response was to overwrite with the last job of the same name.

[image: See here]